# Multiplication rule for probability and separate sample spaces?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

It's my understanding the multiplication rule for dependent events is the following:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B\mid A) = P(B)P(A\mid B)$$

For independent events:

$$P(B\mid A) = P(B)$$

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

I'm getting confused from the set theoretic definition because some authors use this rule with separate sample spaces for event $A$ and $B$.  It's my understanding that the two events must intersect $A \cap B$. With two separate disjoint sample spaces the intersection would be $P(\emptyset)$. Is this practice correct?  For example:

[image: img1]

Here is another example of the sample space being changed.  I'm unsure how $P(B|A) = P(B \cap A)/P(A)$ would be calculated because of change in sample space.  Also, why is this problem calculated as if the events were independent vs using the just mentioned formula?

[image: img2]

Comment: The problem given is not wrong. But you don't want to think of your sample space as being the two separate spaces. Since your experiment is the result of a die roll and a coin flip, you want to think of your sample space as being $\{(c,d):c=T \text{ or } H, d = 1,...,6\}$. So the sample space should actually be pairs of coin flips and die rolls. i.e. the cartesian product of possible coin states and possible die states.

Comment: @Bears thats what I thought but I frequently see authors changing the sample space.  In the cartesian product example there is no intersection of two events.  One finds the probability of a single event in the sample space.

Comment: What do you mean that there's no intersection of two events?

If I want to know the probability that I roll a 6 and the coin ends up as tails, then I look at the probability of the set $\{(c,d):c=T, \text{ and } d=6\}$. This set is non-empty and has exactly one element; namely the element $(T,6)$

Comment: To put it a little more set theoretically, I would look at $\{(T,d):d=1,...,6\}\cap\{(c,6): c=T \text{ or } H\}$

Comment: This last example makes sense for $P(A \cap B)$ and results in $P(A)P(B) = (6/12)*(2/12) = 12/144 = 1/12$ which is the answer in the example.  I'm still confused how using multiple sample spaces is allowed in these examples and the case of dependent events in the second example